# How to save a query in SQL Server using a trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-update

How to save a query in SQL Server using a trigger?

I have a database that supplies different applications. I have detected that one of them is updating a column to null. I want to save the query that does it, so I can know which application is having this error.

Is there a way to save the query that executes a trigger?

Comment: No. If you want a copy of the query being run then set up a/some extended events so that you can record the statements that are being executed, and then find the "troublesome" one from there. *Hopefully* your application(s) pass their name in the connection string so you can easily filter them out.

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately I do not manage the applications only the database, and what I have right now is the user (the same for almost everyone) and the execution date.

Comment: You can't get details of queries run retrospectively; you'll need to create the XEvents now and then await for the issue to happen again to work out what query it is that is causing the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Can you share a link with me on how to do that?

Comment: Start with the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/quick-start-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). Also Grant Fritchey has [compiled a list of great articles](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/04/20/the-very-best-of-extended-events/) on them.

Comment: If you are going to dabble with extended events, [sp_humanevents](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sp_humanevents/sp_humanevents-humanizing-extended-events/) is recommended. Also if you just want to find potential culprit queries you can search the *plan cache* for updates on the offending column.